# How do I write a script to run multiple processes in the background and have additional commands run once each individual command completes?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to do something like the following in a bash script:

```
for x in a b c; do echo foo $x; sleep 5 & y=$! ; (wait $y && echo bar $x) & done
```

Is this possible, without adding much complexity (the above example of course does not actually work)?

EDIT:

Of course in reality, `echo foo $x; sleep 5` would be for example, copying some large file or compiling something big, and the second operation would be operations that depend on the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but what about using `()`s and putting the `&` on the entire sub group command...

```
for i in 1 2 3; do (echo $i; sleep 5; echo end $i)& done
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I just noticed that too. I'd still be interested if there's a simple way to wait on different background processes simultaneously as suggested in my question.

Comment: That is basically what the `;` and `&&` syntax is for.